# Changes required to make new plugin from existing

Tags: plugins, php

I have a gallery plugin script I found here: http://wp.rosselliot.co.nz/user-images/

This allows users of my site to upload their own gallery photos -- these photos can only been seen by the uploader which is also a plus for me. In fact, I like it so much I want to deploy it again on my site ( I know this may not make sense to some, but I have a very specific Idea).
So my question is: What changes do I need to make to this plugin script to make wordpress think this is a completely different plugin, and allow me to deploy it without errors.

I have tried adding I have tried changing call the "sui" with "sui2" but its giving me errors still, I don't know much about how the plugins communicate with wordpress.

The Code:
submit_user_images.php

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Submit User Images
Plugin URI: http://wp.rosselliot.co.nz/user-images/
Description: Allows registered users to submit images.
Version: 1.0
License: GPLv2
Author: Ross Elliot
Author URI: http://wp.rosselliot.co.nz
*/

define('MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE', 200000);
define('TYPE_WHITELIST', serialize(array(
  'image/jpeg',
  'image/png',
  'image/gif'
  )));


add_shortcode('sui_form', 'sui_form_shortcode');


function sui_form_shortcode(){

  if(!is_user_logged_in()){

    return '<p>You need to be logged in to submit an image.</p>';    

  }

  global $current_user;

  if(isset( $_POST['sui_upload_image_form_submitted'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['sui_upload_image_form_submitted'], 'sui_upload_image_form') ){  

    $result = sui_parse_file_errors($_FILES['sui_image_file'], $_POST['sui_image_caption']);

    if($result['error']){

      echo '<p>ERROR: ' . $result['error'] . '</p>';

    }else{

      $user_image_data = array(
        'post_title' => $result['caption'],
        'post_status' => 'pending',
        'post_author' => $current_user->ID,
        'post_type' => 'user_images'     
      );

      if($post_id = wp_insert_post($user_image_data)){

        sui_process_image('sui_image_file', $post_id, $result['caption']);

        wp_set_object_terms($post_id, (int)$_POST['sui_image_category'], 'sui_image_category');

      }
    }
  }  

  if (isset( $_POST['sui_form_delete_submitted'] ) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['sui_form_delete_submitted'], 'sui_form_delete')){

    if(isset($_POST['sui_image_delete_id'])){

      if($user_images_deleted = sui_delete_user_images($_POST['sui_image_delete_id'])){        

        echo '<p>' . $user_images_deleted . ' images(s) deleted!</p>';

      }
    }
  }


  echo sui_get_upload_image_form($sui_image_caption = $_POST['sui_image_caption'], $sui_image_category = $_POST['sui_image_category']);

  if($user_images_table = sui_get_user_images_table($current_user->ID)){

    echo $user_images_table;

  }

}


function sui_delete_user_images($images_to_delete){

  $images_deleted = 0;

  foreach($images_to_delete as $user_image){

    if (isset($_POST['sui_image_delete_id_' . $user_image]) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['sui_image_delete_id_' . $user_image], 'sui_image_delete_' . $user_image)){

      if($post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($user_image)){

        wp_delete_attachment($post_thumbnail_id);      

      }  

      wp_trash_post($user_image);

      $images_deleted ++;

    }
  }

  return $images_deleted;

}


function sui_get_user_images_table($user_id){

  $args = array(
    'author' => $user_id,
    'post_type' => 'user_images',
    'post_status' => 'pending'    
  );

  $user_images = new WP_Query($args);

  if(!$user_images->post_count) return 0;

  $out = '';
  $out .= '<p>Click to see full size</p>';

  $out .= '<form method="post" action="">';

  $out .= wp_nonce_field('sui_form_delete', 'sui_form_delete_submitted');  

  $out .= '<table id="user_images">';
  $out .= '<thead><th>Image</th><th>Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Delete</th></thead>';

  foreach($user_images->posts as $user_image){

    $user_image_cats = get_the_terms($user_image->ID, 'sui_image_category');

   foreach($user_image_cats as $cat){

      $user_image_cat = $cat->name;

    }

    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($user_image->ID);   

    $out .= wp_nonce_field('sui_image_delete_' . $user_image->ID, 'sui_image_delete_id_' . $user_image->ID, false); 

    $out .= '<tr>';
    $out .= '<td>' . wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail') . '</td>';    
    $out .= '<td>' . $user_image->post_title . '</td>';
    $out .= '<td>' . $user_image_cat . '</td>';    
    $out .= '<td><input type="checkbox" name="sui_image_delete_id[]" value="' . $user_image->ID . '" /></td>';          
    $out .= '</tr>';

  }

  $out .= '</table>';

  $out .= '<input type="submit" name="sui_delete" value="Delete Selected Images" />';
  $out .= '</form>';  

  return $out;

}


function sui_process_image($file, $post_id, $caption){

  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
  require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

  $attachment_id = media_handle_upload($file, $post_id);

  update_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attachment_id);

  $attachment_data = array(
    'ID' => $attachment_id,
    'post_excerpt' => $caption
  );

  wp_update_post($attachment_data);

  return $attachment_id;

}


function sui_parse_file_errors($file = '', $image_caption){

  $result = array();
  $result['error'] = 0;

  if($file['error']){

    $result['error'] = "No file uploaded or there was an upload error!";

    return $result;

  }

  $image_caption = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/', ' ', $image_caption));

  if($image_caption == ''){

    $result['error'] = "Your caption may only contain letters, numbers and spaces!";

    return $result;

  }

  $result['caption'] = $image_caption;  

  $image_data = getimagesize($file['tmp_name']);

  if(!in_array($image_data['mime'], unserialize(TYPE_WHITELIST))){

    $result['error'] = 'Your image must be a jpeg, png or gif!';

  }elseif(($file['size'] > MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE)){

    $result['error'] = 'Your image was ' . $file['size'] . ' bytes! It must not exceed ' . MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE . ' bytes.';

  }

  return $result;

}



function sui_get_upload_image_form($sui_image_caption = '', $sui_image_category = 0){

  $out = '';
  $out .= '<form id="sui_upload_image_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">';

  $out .= wp_nonce_field('sui_upload_image_form', 'sui_upload_image_form_submitted');

  $out .= '<label for="sui_image_caption">Image Caption - Letters, Numbers and Spaces</label><br/>';
  $out .= '<input type="text" id="sui_image_caption" name="sui_image_caption" value="' . $sui_image_caption . '"/><br/>';
  $out .= '<label for="sui_image_category">Image Category</label><br/>';  
  $out .= sui_get_image_categories_dropdown('sui_image_category', $sui_image_category) . '<br/>';
  $out .= '<label for="sui_image_file">Select Your Image - ' . MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE . ' bytes maximum</label><br/>';  
  $out .= '<input type="file" size="60" name="sui_image_file" id="sui_image_file"><br/>';

  $out .= '<input type="submit" id="sui_submit" name="sui_submit" value="Upload Image">';

  $out .= '</form>';

  return $out;

}


function sui_get_image_categories_dropdown($taxonomy, $selected){

  return wp_dropdown_categories(array('taxonomy' => $taxonomy, 'name' => 'sui_image_category', 'selected' => $selected, 'hide_empty' => 0, 'echo' => 0));

}


add_action('init', 'sui_plugin_init');

function sui_plugin_init(){

  $image_type_labels = array(
    'name' => _x('User images', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('User Image', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New User Image', 'image'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New User Image'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit User Image'),
    'new_item' => __('Add New User Image'),
    'all_items' => __('View User Images'),
    'view_item' => __('View User Image'),
    'search_items' => __('Search User Images'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No User Images found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No User Images found in Trash'), 
    'parent_item_colon' => '',
    'menu_name' => 'User Images'
  );

  $image_type_args = array(
    'labels' => $image_type_labels,
    'public' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true, 
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'map_meta_cap' => true,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail')
  ); 

  register_post_type('user_images', $image_type_args);

  $image_category_labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'User Image Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'User Image', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search User Image Categories' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All User Image Categories' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent User Image Category' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent User Image Category:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit User Image Category' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update User Image Category' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New User Image Category' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New User Image Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'User Image Categories' ),
  );    

  $image_category_args = array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $image_category_labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'user_image_category' ),
  );

  register_taxonomy('sui_image_category', array('user_images'), $image_category_args);

  $default_image_cats = array('Suspect', 'Vehicle', 'Residence', 'Other');

  foreach($default_image_cats as $cat){

    if(!term_exists($cat, 'sui_image_category')) wp_insert_term($cat, 'sui_image_category');

  }

}
```

user_images_template.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: user_images
 *
 *
 */

get_header(); ?>

<div id="container">
  <div id="content" role="main">

<h2>All Approved User Images</h2>

<?php
  global $current_user;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'user_images',
    'post_status' => 'publish'    
  );

  $posts = new WP_Query($args);

  if($posts->post_count){;

    $out = '';
    $out .= '<table id="user_images">';
    $out .= '<thead><th>Image</th><th>Caption</th><th>Category</th><th>Posted By</th></thead>';

    foreach($posts->posts as $user_image){

      $user_info = get_userdata($user_image->post_author);    

      $user_image_cats = get_the_terms($user_image->ID, 'sui_image_category');

      foreach($user_image_cats as $cat){

        $user_image_cat = $cat->name;

      }

      $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id($user_image->ID);   

      $out .= '<tr>';
      $out .= '<td>' . wp_get_attachment_link($post_thumbnail_id, 'thumbnail') . '</td>';    
      $out .= '<td>' . $user_image->post_title . '</td>';
      $out .= '<td>' . $user_image_cat . '</td>';    
      $out .= '<td>' . $user_info->user_login . '</td>';      
      $out .= '</tr>';

    }

    $out .= '</table>';

    echo $out;

  }else{

    echo 'No images have been approved for publication!';

  }

?>




  </div><!-- #content -->

</div><!-- #container -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: change functions and variable names, also change the name of the metadata (fields ou save to the db) and the input elements, or not, depending if you are intending to use both plugins. Change the name of the plugin and the name of the folder.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds like a tedious and tricky task.. perhaps I will try to think of other options. Thanks again